# Creating a broadcast intent based on a shell am command

Tags: android, shell, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I'm working with the OWASP Goat Droid project. The app has the following intent-filter for broadcasts:

```
[...]
        <receiver android:label="Send SMS" android:name=".broadcastreceivers.SendSMSNowReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="org.owasp.goatdroid.fourgoats.SOCIAL_SMS"/>
            </intent-filter> &gt;
        </receiver>
[...]
```

I can use the interactive shell on the device to successfully send a broadcast to this package/class/intent-filter (still not sure about the correct term here), with the following command:

```
adb shell
am broadcast –a MyBroadcastAction –n org.owasp.goatdroid.fourgoats/.broadcastreceivers.SendSMSNowReceiver –-es phoneNumber 1234-–es message “Test”
```

I'm trying write an app, where the exact same action is applied. The following code is executed in a new Activity, upon pressing a button.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("MyBroadcastAction ");

    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName("org.owasp.goatdroid.fourgoats", ".broadcastreceivers.SendSMSNowReceiver");
    intent.setComponent(componentName);

    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putString("phoneNumber","1234");
    extras.putString("message","APP_Test");
    intent.putExtras(extras);

    sendBroadcast(intent);
```

The Goat Droid does not receive the application and upon investigating it seems like the broadcast isn't sent.

```
adb shell
dumpsys activity broadcasts | grep -B 10 -A 10 goat
```

This only shows the broadcasts I've sent from the interactive shell.

How do I correctly send the broadcast, as shown with the interactive shell, in app form?

*edit:* The Goat Droid app is installed on an AVD (API level 24) and the app starting the intent shown above is started directly via the Android SDK on the AVD.

---

**EDIT: SOLVED**

Yet I'm not quite sure how/why. Came to the solution after reading [this blog article](http://hmkcode.com/android-sending-receiving-custom-broadcasts/). The following code works for me:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("org.owasp.goatdroid.fourgoats.SOCIAL_SMS");
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putString("phoneNumber","1234");
    extras.putString("message","test");
    intent.putExtras(extras);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
```

I had to create the intent with the appropriate action, which was not needed for the interactive shell am command.